# reset \setbeamertemplate{} instructions

Tags: beamer, itemize, text, size

in my presentation I alter the dimension of nested "itemize" items, e.g.:

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\small}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subsubbody begin}{\tiny}
```

would it be possible to reset these modifications to the default values 
(without manually specifying them, which I don't know)  ?

Answer (score 3):

No need to reset the template if you keep the modification inside a group:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

{
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\tiny}
\begin{itemize}
\item bla
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{itemize}
\item blub
\end{itemize}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was aware of that ...  anyway if no better option comes out it could be a solution.